# How to assign NameSpace.Class to a object by string

Tags: c#, string, methods

Looking to create a Windows service which runs multiple jobs on independent threads. I want to assign the jobs via a sql table Job - (nameSpace,jobName,interval,enabled etc)

So when I add a new dll for a job to the solution the factory adds the class.
That way I can add new jobs without compile, install etc.
I have a generic interface called `IJob` which has `StartTask` call among others.

Now after loading my job records from the table how do I assign the class (with `IJob`) loaded by the dll by name (`string`) so that I can use it's methods.

Each namespace and class follows the same pattern CompanyName.JobName

Example below

I've tried looking up `delegates` (something I'm not overly familiar with I admit) but I can only find invokes, I don't want to call it, I want to assign it so I can refer to it later.

```
List<IJob> runningTasks = new List<IJob>();

private void RunJobs (List<Job> jobs)
{
 foreach (var job in jobs)
 {
    IJob task = GetClass(job.nameSpace,job.jobName);
    task.StartTask(job);
    runningTasks.Add(task);
 }
}
private IJob GetClass(string nameSpace, string jobName)
{
    No idea what to put in here....
}
private void StopJobs()
{
   foreach (var task in runningTasks)
   {
      task.StopTask(job);
   }
 }
private double GetJobProgress(string jobName)
{
   IJob task = runningTasks.Single(x=>x.jobName = jobName);
   return task.GetProgress();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple: `IJob job = (IJob)Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath).CreateInstance($"{nameSpace}.{jobName}");` Put a try/catch around it.

Comment: Are you trying to re-write the task scheduler? The task scheduler has an API you can use to interact with it. If all you are trying to do is run another program (an .exe, a .net core dll, ect.), you could just write a program that reads the required info for a job from a database, and then calls the task scheduler to trigger that job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm renaming GetClass() to CreateJob() because that's a better description of what it does.

You'll want to put a try/catch around the call to CreateJob(), in case the assembly doesn't exist, or that class isn't defined in it, or there's a class by that name in that namespace, but it doesn't implement `IJob`, or it's there but it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

```
private IJob CreateJob(string nameSpace, string jobName)
{
    //  This part is unclear: It sounds like you're loading assemblies from files dynamically, 
    //  but it's not clear how you locate them. This assumes the assembly names are the same 
    //  as the namespace, and they're all in a directory called "jobs"
    var assemblyPath = $"jobs\\{nameSpace}.dll";

    return (IJob)Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath).CreateInstance($"{nameSpace}.{jobName}");
}
```

If the jobs are all in assemblies that are already linked, it's even easier:

```
private IJob CreateJob(string nameSpace, string jobName)
{
    return (IJob)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"{nameSpace}.{jobName}"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately when i try 

    return (IJob)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($" 
               {CompanyName}." + job.jobName));

the try catch is triggered saying Type is Null.
the curly braces seem to force check to see if it already exists?

Comment: Never mind i stupidly forgot the class name as well Thank you for the Help.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if you have all the assemblies loaded that contain the needed classes. If not, you might want to refer to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-load-assemblies-into-an-application-domain) on dynamically loading assemblies into your application domain and then creating instances of classes defined in it.
And I hope they all implement the exact same `IJob` interface (from the exact same assembly which you also refer in your code).

Just skip the method call part in the example and you should achieve the goal

```
private IJob GetClass(string nameSpace, string jobName)
{
    // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
    // application domain.
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load($"{nameSpace}.dll");
    // Get the type to use.
    Type myType = a.GetType($"{nameSpace}.{jobname}");
    // Create an instance.
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

    return (IJob)obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this along the same lines as ed's and works.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your `GetClass` like below:

```
private object GetClass(string nspace, string jobname)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(nspace).Append(".").Append(jobname);
  string strFullyQualifiedName = sb.ToString();
  Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
  if (type != null) return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
  {
    type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
    if (type != null)
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked too, Ed Plunketts answer was a bit cleaner for me